# convert 'this' pointer from item to const Item & compiler errors

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors, set

Can you explain me why the following error happens and How I can fix the problem? It gives me a lot of problems so please I need your help

the error(compilation error) -

> `the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the
>   member function`

*the items member is a set

the problem line -

```
temp.setName(items.find(itemList[option])->getName());
```

the setName and the getName functions -

```
void Item::setName(string name)
{
    this->_name = name;
}
string Item::getName()
{
    return this->_name;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is not const-correct. The set will only allow constant methods on it's contents:

```
string Item::getName() const
{
    return this->_name;
}
```